# EasyTracker of google analytics not working

Tags: android, google-analytics

1. Update AndroidManifest.xml
2. Add tracking methods
3. Create your analytics.xml file

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Every Activity:**

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
}
```

**analytics.xml** in **values** folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
    xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:ignore="TypographyDashes"
    >

    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA–XXXXXXXX–1</string>

    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

</resources>
```

This was working fine a few days back. But for the past 2-3 days, thought i am using(testing) the app, i don't see any data from Google.

After some research i found this:

```
Replace “-” with an “en dash” character (–, &&;#8211;)
```

If this was the case, it shouldn't have worked previously. But i tried changing it, still no data.

Anything else i am missing?

**EDIT:**

There was an Old installer for which GA was working, later i changed few things and re-built the installer, but i haven't changed anything in the Manifest like version, app_name etc.., Even now if i am using the old installer GA works and for the New installer it doesn't. If interested, the things i changed in the installer are **URLs** (Web server i am using). This might be a reason?

Thank You

Comment: Looks like EasyTracker is no longer available in Google Analytics v4. I do not see it in the Google Play Services library project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
    xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:ignore="TypographyDashes"
    >

    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-1</string>

    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

</resources>
```

I am using the normal dashes, and added `tools:ignore="TypographyDashes"` but it still shows the lint warning. But works.

Comment: This is now described on the Google Analytics documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/

Answer (score 0):

EasyTrackers configuration in analytics.xml does currently not support package rewriting via

```
aapt --rename-manifest-package new.package.name
```

If you use this you cannot use EasyTracker until that changes.

Watch these two issues:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/analytics/rename-manifest-package